# C# Task.Run does not await action variable

Tags: c#, lambda, async-await, task

See example codes.

```
Console.WriteLine("start")
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
});
Console.WriteLine("end");

// result 
// start [3s delay] end
```

It works!
but below code is not working.

```
Action action = async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
};
Console.WriteLine("start")
Task.Run(action);
Console.WriteLine("end");

// result
// start [without delay] end
```

Why `Task.Run` does not await async action variable?

edit -------------------------

I'm so sorry. I wrote wrong code.
This is right code.

I test it on C# Interactive of VS 2017

```
Console.WriteLine("start");
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
});
Console.WriteLine("end");

Action action = async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
};
Console.WriteLine("start");
await Task.Run(action);
Console.WriteLine("end");
```

Comment: Not sure where are you testing, but the first example does NOT wait for the delay: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TP3J37

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Sorry, I wrote wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to use async and Tasks, is to make two or more methods to run simultaneously. So your method will continue running and when finished the delay, will call anything after the delay since you run another async func in a task.

If you run this method, You'll notice

> finished

will be printed in the middle of the other work ( and here the other work is `for loop`,

```
Console.WriteLine("start");
Task.Run(async () =>
 {
     await Task.Delay(200);
      Console.WriteLine("Finished");
 });

 for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
Console.WriteLine("end");
Console.ReadKey();
```

> For some reason, It doesn't work as expected on dotnetfiddle

Even if you didn't run async in the task, they will run simultaneously.

Look at this example :

```
 Console.WriteLine("start");
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Task.Delay(2000).Wait(); // Will NOT wait !
                Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            });

            for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("end");
            Console.ReadKey();
```

> It'll continue without any delay since it's on a Task

But if you want the method to wait, First : Don't run it on a Task.
Second : call the Wait() method.

Like :

```
Console.WriteLine("start");

Task.Delay(2000).Wait(); // It'll wait for 2 seconds before continue.

for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(i);
  }
 Console.WriteLine("end");
 Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `Task.Run` without an await, this will just 'fire and forget'. Code execution will not wait for it, and it will simply run it as soon as a `thread` is available from the `thread pool`.

Typically, if you want to off load some work and wait for that work to be finished, create a separate method that returns a `Task`, then `await` that.

**Example**:

```
Console.WriteLine("start")
await DoWorkAsync();
Console.WriteLine("end");

/////////
private Task DoWorkAsync()
{
  return Task.Run(async () =>
  {
     await Task.Delay(3000);
  });
}
```

Note that wrapping a method body into a `Task` and returning it, is not suggested, and it typically leads to a bit of a code smell.

Stephen Cleary has good information about `Tasks` and `async/await`. I would read up on this:

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Answer (score 0):

Will work like this, not that obvious though:

```
Func<Task> action = async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
};

Console.WriteLine("start");
await Task.Run(action);
Console.WriteLine("end");
```

Answer (score -2):

You may try this:

```
Action action = async () =>
                {
                    await Task.Delay(3000);
                };
                Console.WriteLine("start");
                Task.Run(action).Wait();                
                Console.WriteLine("end");
```

Comment: And why this should work since it's a copy from the question ? by the way : It doesn't wait !

Comment: It's not just a copy, I've added .Wait(); on line# 6, It would work for you bro, Try it please

Comment: Not working :) . Since you are running on a task, it doesn't wait. I added an example about your method before , read my answer and you'll see why it doesn't wait.

Comment: @Kaj What you provided is Task.Delay(2000).Wait(); which is totally different than what I said bro. My code is working 100% percent

Comment: Though you are missing the point. Since you are running on a task, it'll not wait ! As I tried it and It' does NOT wait.